# Create trigger to insert row after record has been updated

Tags: sql, triggers

I have an issue with a trigger that I have created.

The trigger that I have currently fires every time the row is updated. This is fine in most scenarios, but it seems that the way the code was written to update the table is not what I would expect.

Say I have a table that stores the file that was uploaded. This table has 10 columns.

And I have a trigger that logs what has been inserted / updated / deleted. This audit table has 4 columns.

```
File_Name, File_Content, Upload_Date, User
```

Currently when I perform an upload, which does an insert into the Database, it will first add the entry

```
TestFile.txt, null, 15-10-2017, ALEX
```

After which it will perform the updates, which ends with

```
TestFile.txt, ABCDEF, 15-01-2017, ALEX.
```

With this, think of about 5 more columns that are updated one by one.

This has caused my update trigger to insert 5 rows into the `Audit` table.

Is there any way to get just the content of the row that was updated and do an insert?

Below is my current trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER upload_audit_trigger_overwrite 
AFTER UPDATE 
ON _sys_repo.active_object 
REFERENCING NEW ROW mynewrow 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO _sys_repo.upload_audit 
            (file_name, uploaded_by, uploaded_date, 
             action, cdata, version_id) 
    VALUES (:mynewrow.object_name, :mynewrow.activated_by, :mynewrow.activated_at, 
            'OVERWRITE', :mynewrow.cdata, :mynewrow.version_id); 
END;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to triggers many products aren't fully ANSI compliant.)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find the answer myself. I will just compare the old data and the new data based on a pattern on another column and if it differs, I will update.

Below is my change.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upload_audit_trigger_test AFTER 
INSERT, 
UPDATE 
ON _sys_repo.active_object REFERENCING NEW ROW mynewrow, 
       OLD ROW myoldrow FOR EACH ROW BEGIN WHEN updating THEN IF :mynewrow.version_id <> :myoldrow.version_id THEN
INSERT INTO _sys_repo.upload_audit 
            ( 
                        file_name, 
                        uploaded_by, 
                        uploaded_date, 
                        action, 
                        cdata, 
                        version_id 
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ( 
                        :mynewrow.object_name, 
                        :mynewrow.activated_by, 
                        :mynewrow.activated_at, 
                        'OVERWRITE', 
                        :mynewrow.cdata, 
                        :mynewrow.version_id 
            ); 

END IF; 
END;
```